# Checking for two values within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to utilize a single `for` loop in Python to

1. Check for the largest number within a `list` then print the index it was found
2. Count the frequency of that largest number within the `list`.

   ```
   for index in range(1, listLength):
       if numbersList[index] > numbersList[largest]:
           largest = index
   ```

I have part 1 complete, however, I am unsure how I can then search for the frequency of it within the same for loop.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set the counter to 1 when you find a new largest number, as you do in your condition, increment it if you find a number that is equal to your largest one.

Comment: Why you want in single loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the loop at all to achieve this. Sort the list and find the number at the last index and use count(number) to get the number of occurences.

```
numbers = [1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers.sort() 
print(numbers) 
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

list.count(number)

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5].count(5)
1
```

or you can use import the below one

```
 from collections import Counter
 Counter(list)
```

will give you the output count in dictionary format.

```
Counter({'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 2, '5': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are inbuilt methods to do these.

```
In [110]: lst = [1,2,4,5,66,7,7,4,66,78,1]
In [111]: max(lst)
Out[111]: 78
```

1.Check for the largest number within a list then print the index it was found,

```
In [112]: print lst.index(max(lst))
Out[112]: 9
```

2.Count the frequency of that largest number within the list.

```
In [113]: print lst.count(max(lst))
Out[113]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use built-in functions then,  take an integer e.g `Count`. This represents the frequency of the largest number. Go through the array once and when you find a new largest number set `largest = index` and `counter = 0.` Add a condition that if the current number is equal to your saved largest number then increment the `count` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any libraries, you can achieve it by using below code:

```
counter = 1
for index in range(listLength):
    if index == 0:
        largest = 0
    if numbersList[index] == numbersList[largest]:
        counter += 1
    elif numbersList[index] > numbersList[largest]:
        counter = 1
        largest = index
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways around this

```
a = [1, 9, 3, 7, 5, 9, 7, 4, 9, 5] # test_data
```

1. `max()` and `count`

   ```
   largest = max(a)
   print(largest)          # 9
   print(a.count(largest)) # 3
   ```

   Usually, above is the most common and widely used way of getting largest number and counting elements in the list.
2. `max()` and `Counter`

   ```
   from collections import Counter
   c = Counter(a)
   print(c[max(a)]) # 3
   ```

   `Counter` is from `collections` and it supports various kinds of methods. For more, please refer to this website: https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-counter/